# Is it unnecessary to put preposition phrase describing person affected after linking verb

Tags: verbs

For example, If we think of this sentence "You're famous". And what if I want to describe particular place you are famous or to some group that you are famous? So I thought of way "You're famous to bla bla people" or "you're famous in bla bla place" Does it make sense?

I got to wonder this while reading this sentnece. In this part in bold "remain essentially unknown", although following phrase start with "without anyone.." explains to whom he remained unknown, I wondered if that phrase could be replaced to "remain essentially unknown **to**..."

> That exactly twenty years after Howie Rubin became a scandalous household name for losing $250 million, another mortgage bond trader named Howie, inside Morgan Stanley, would lose $9 billion on a single mortgage trade, and **remain essentially unknown**, without anyone beyond a small circle inside Morgan Stanley ever hearing about what he'd done, or why.—The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine by Michael Lewis—

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fame generally implies among a wide circle of people but it's fair enough to say that someone **is famous in the club/school/organisation for** something or other.

**Famous to....** sounds most unlikely.

But you can be **famous among** certain people, **famous for** certain achievements, and **famous in/around** these parts.

There may well be other prepositions that fit.